# Change Server IP, How to change Windows DNS record?

Tags: domain-name-system, iis-6

I change My server IP. I have about 1000 dns A record on my windows dns , and have to change the value of this records,
Is it possible that run a command , script to change the IP address on all records not changing one by one?

Also, is it possible to change IP address of All sites on  IIS websites?

Thanks

Comment: I am curious how you have a thousand DNS records pointing to a single server?

Comment: I have 200 Domains, and each one has 5 A record,it's a share hsoting service

Comment: To avoid such problems in the future, use CNAME instead of A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to take a copy of your dns zone file and open it with an advanced text editor, such as Notepad++ and perform a find & replace on the records.  Once the file is updated, stop your dns server, replace the existing zone file with your modified one and start the dns server.

Comment: I just can see Export list per Zone , but I can't find how can I restore modified files.

Comment: Use both techniques - DNSCMD to export your zone to a text file (I'm assuming it's AD-integrated), then edit the file (find & replace) and use DNSCMD again to re-import the edited file.

Comment: I find a folde called dns ( windows\system32\dns) and the open all dns files, the replace IPs and restart dns server.

Comment: @Ashian .. did this work?

Comment: @tomjedrz : yes that work :)

Comment: @Ashian.. good to hear you figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using dnscmd.  Test the first change from the command prompt using dnscmd.  To learn the syntax, use dnscmd /?.

Then create a batch file (i.e. runme.bat) or use powershell, whichever you prefer, with all of the commands.

For IIS, use appcmd from c:\windows\system32\inetsrv.  Likely, use appcmd /? to get the syntax, or post back here for more assistance on the specifics.

Comment: both command not running,and not recognized as internal command, which is base folder?

Comment: appcmd is new for IIS7, so if you are using a prior version it won't be there.  adsutil.vbs is the best command line option prior to appcmd.

dnscmd should be in your path on your DNS server.  It won't exist on a client machine though.